# MogoDB findAndModify return WriteResult

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I do query with logic "insert if not exists". Can i return upsert result without additional queries ?

```
 var u = Builders<Blog>.Update
                .SetOnInsert(f => f.BlogId, blogId)
                .SetOnInsert(f => f.VideoId, videoId)
                -- other fields...

var blog = Blog.FindOneAndUpdate<Blog>(c => c.BlogId == blogId && c.VideoId == VideoId, u, 
   new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Blog>{IsUpsert = true, ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After}
);

bool wasUpsert =  ? 
return wasUpsert;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `new: true` option, see [4.0 release notes](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/4.0-Release-Notes#backwards-breaking-changes).

```
Milestone.findOneAndUpdate({
    ......
}, {
    ......
}, {upsert: true, 'new': true}, function(err, res) {
    // err === null
    // res === null
    done(err, res);
});
```

Comment: #2262: The findOneAndUpdate(), findByIdAndUpdate(), etc. new option is now false by default. The MongoDB server assumes false by default, this change is so mongoose is more consistent with the server's API.

Comment: i dont understand how apply on lastest official C# driver

Comment: i dont need document before or after, i need bool logic result was or no insert new document

Comment: It will actually be a boolean in the updatedExisting field of true or false.

Comment: if return {blogid:1 , video: 1} and ? how i can check its return because exists document no upsert or its new inserted document ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
var filter = Builders<MyCollectionModel>.Filter
    .Eq(x => x.Id, ObjectId.Parse("5ecd93f739a1c716ab2c2d44"));
var update = Builders<MyCollectionModel>.Update.Set(x => x.Email, "john.smith@gmail.com");
var updateResult = await context.MyCollectionModel
    .UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true});
updateResult.Dump(); // LINQPad
```

Then if a document with that id exists but no change was made you will get:

[image]

if a document with that id exists and the email was changed you will get:

[image]

and finally, if the document did not exist and therefore it was added, `UpsertedId` will show its id.